# Divergence of Unusual Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I already prove this series.

If $u_n > 0$ and $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \le 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{\alpha}{n\log n}$, where $\alpha >1$, then $\sum u_n$ converges.

However, I could not prove the next series.

If $u_n > 0$ and $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \ge 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n\log n}$, then $\sum u_n$ diverges.

---

My idea was as follows.
$ 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n\log n} \gt \frac12 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n\log n} $

series of right hand side is not going to zero, so its summation of the series does diverge.

So, I wrongly thought that this is proven.

However, I realized that this property is not related to the summation of $u_n$.

Is there anybody has a great idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you show what you did? It may be that the idea to second point lies where you couldn't prove that the first point was valid for $\alpha=1$.

Comment: @Martigan look the eqaution again. Second series is totally different from first series. Second one is not the case of $\alpha=1$ of first one. The inequaltity of second one is reverse.

Comment: It is not "completely different", as the expression on the RHS is the same... You did not manage to prove the convergence for $\alpha=1$ in the first case, maybe because instead of converging, your expression leads to diverging (as it could be the case)... Since you now state that the ratio is bigger, this is a possible clue to the solution.

Comment: I think the way of proving second one might be totally different from first one. In the first one, I think we can use the property that $\log (1-x) \lt -x$.

Comment: @MathforyourLife: there *is* a relation. If the first one could be proven for $\alpha=1$, then the second would be false (look at the case of equality -- for $\alpha=1$, both the first and the second inequalities cover this case, so the difference lies at $\alpha=1$)

Comment: OMG. I realized it. I was stupid.

Comment: Incidentally (and for reference), this type of condition is related to/captured by a theorem called [Bertrand's Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BertrandsTest.html) and Kummer's Test, both generalizations of d'Alembert's ratio test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** for the second one, and assuming you are allowed to use this theorem, applying [Kummer's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Higher_order_tests) with $a_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} (n\ln n )\ln\ln n$ will allow you* to conclude that a series $\sum_n u_n$ with positive terms and such that $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = 1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n\ln n}$$ diverges. Once this is done, the cases where $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} > 1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ follow easily.

* If I did not screw up my computations.

Answer (score 0):

If first statement is true, in the case of the equality of second one at $\alpha=1$, the second one diverges....

Moreover, in the remainingg other case, by the ratio test, it does diverge!

I just realized it by the commnets of two wise men.

I was doing this for 2 hours even though I already proved it........

---

This method has a problem.

We have to use other way.

Comment: I'm actually not sure to understand your argument. The comments above, the way I interpret them, boil down to arguing that the techniques you used to prove the first point may give you some insight to prove the second, as they have to "break down" for $\alpha=1$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. I meant that, when equality holds, if $\alpha =1$, second series diverges by the result from the proof of first one. and, when LHS is bigger than RHS, by the ratio test, it would diverge.

Comment: So, basically, when looking at your proof for the first item (that is not written above), you have a part that gives, for the case $\alpha=1$, divergence of the series? (I am trying to make clear what the solution you end up having is -- as your detailed solution for the first item itself appears nowhere on this page)